# Prove that $1+x+y$ not equal to $xy$, when $x$ and $y$ are positive odd numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was engaging in this equation and with the help of desmos.com I noticed it is not possible. So how can we prove? In which way it is easier, should I leave $x$ or $y$ alone, or is there any method different?

Comment: Hint: $\;1+x+y=xy \iff xy-x-y\color{red}{+1} = 1\color{red}{+1} \iff (x-1)(y-1)=2\,$.

Comment: You should make that an answer @dxiv you deserve the points for that!

Comment: @Mike Too late ;-) but I'll upvote the OP if *they* expand it into a full answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks all comments and answers to this question. It is a question can be proved but if we have had 1+x+y+z+t = xt = yz (x+t>y+z) for positive odd numbers , can we solve this, is it impossible? I used the methods you used in first question but did not work.

Comment: @TalhaŞAHİN So you have another question? Please then ask a new question. Do you have any questions about the current answers? Are they comprehensible?

Comment: @callculus No; answers are enough, and they are comprehensible. And the reason why I did not ask the question above (I mean 2nd question) is I did not want to open a new title for the same question (Actually same but detailed more)

Comment: @TalhaŞAHİN They are not the same. They are different. Why not ask a new question? Our answers refering to the first question. To avoid confusion ask a new question for a new problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all we can define odd numbers:

$x=2m-1 \ \  \forall \ m \in \mathbb N \ \backslash \{0\}$ and $y=2n-1 \ \  \forall \ n \in \mathbb N \ \backslash \{0\}$

Then we have $1+x+y=x\cdot y\Rightarrow -1+2m+2n=(2m-1)(2n-1)$

$2m+2n-1=4mn-2m-2n+1$

$4m+4n=4mn+2$

$2(m+n)=2mn+1$

The LHS is always even and the RHS is always odd for all $n,m \in \mathbb N \ \backslash \{0\}$

Answer (score 2):

Let's say $x \geq 3$ and $y \geq 3$ also. Then $x = 2m + 1$ with $m > 0$ and $y = 2n + 1$ likewise with $n > 0$. Then $1 + x + y = 1 + (2m + 1) + (2n + 1) = 2m + 2n + 3$. But $xy = (2m + 1)(2n$ $+ 1) = 4mn + 2m + 2n + 1$.

This means that $xy > 1 + x + y$, since $xy - (1 + x + y) = 4mn - 2$. Since $m$ and $n$ are both positive, $4mn$ has to be at least 4, which means a minimum difference of 2 between $xy$ and $1 + x + y$.

The case with either $x$ or $y$ equal to 1 should not present any special difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is a somewhat convoluted proof, starting with a mod $6$ argument.

It is straightforward to see that the only way that $1+x+y\equiv xy$ mod $6$ with $x,y\in\{1,3,5\}$ (i.e., with $x$ and $y$ both odd) is if $\{x,y\}=\{3,5\}$.  Without loss of generality, let's suppose that $x=3u$ and $y=6v-1$, with $u$ odd. The equation now becomes

$$1+3u+(6v-1)=3u(6v-1)$$

which simplifies first to $u+2v=6uv-u$ and then to

$$u+v=3uv$$

But since $u\equiv1$ mod $2$ (i.e., since $u$ is odd), this implies $1+v\equiv v$ mod $2$, which is impossible. So there are no solutions to $1+x+y=xy$ with $x$ and $y$ both odd.

Remark: The argument here is related to the much simpler mod $4$ argument alluded to in dxiv's comment below the OP that the equation $1+x+y=xy$ can be rewritten as $(x-1)(y-1)=2$.

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

$$1+x+y=xy \implies y=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$$
$$=1+\frac{2}{x-1}$$

thus
$$(x,y)=(2,3) \text{ or } (3,2)$$